# My Drawing Tool Leaves Gaps in Drawing After A While

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've been creating this drawing tool that you "draw" on a "canvas" and it will give you the HTML in little div boxes or you can just use it to paint but I've run into this problem where if you draw/write for a prolonged period of time it starts to have gaps. I'm not quite sure what the cause of this is or how to fix it.

If anyone can tell me what the problem is and how to fix it I'd be very appreciative.

Here is the JsBin for it:

https://jsbin.com/senejuq/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Or if you want just the plain code/code snippit:

```js
var click = false;
var xr = [];
var yr = [];
var html = "";
function move() {
  if (click) {
    xr.push(event.clientX);
    yr.push(event.clientY);
    draw(xr[xr.length-1]-Number($('width').value)-5, yr[yr.length-1]-Number($('width').value)-5);
  }
}
function draw(x,y) {
  if ($('brushtype').value == "block") {
  html += "<div style = 'position:absolute; background-color: "+$('color').value+"; width: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; height: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; margin-top: " + y + "px; margin-left:" + x +"px'></div>";
  $('canvas').innerHTML = html + 
    "<div style = 'position:absolute; background-color: " + $('color').value + "; width: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; height: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; margin-top: " + y + "px; margin-left:" + x +"px'></div>";
  } else if ($('brushtype').value == "brush") {
    html += "<div style = 'position:absolute; background-color: "+$('color').value+"; width: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; height: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; margin-top: " + y + "px; margin-left:" + x +"px; border-radius: 300px;'></div>";
    $('canvas').innerHTML = html + 
    "<div style = 'position:absolute; background-color: " + $('color').value + "; width: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; height: "+Number($('width').value)+"px; margin-top: " + y + "px; margin-left:" + x +"px; border-radius:300px;'></div>";
    
  }
}
function ondown() {
  click = true;
  move();
}
function onup() {
  click = false;
}
function $(arg) {
  return document.getElementById(arg);
}
function pasteHTML() {
  $('ta').innerHTML = "<div id = 'drawing' width = '100%' height = '100%'>" + html +"</div>";
}
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}  
#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  
}  
textarea {
  background-color: transparent;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "canvas" onmousedown = "ondown()"
    onmousemove = "move()" onmouseup = "onup()"
  ></div>
  <select id = "brushtype">
    <option value = "block">Block</option>
    <option value = "brush">Brush</option></select>
  <select id = "color">
    <option value = "black">Black</option>
    <option value = "white">White</option>
    <option value = "blue">Blue</option>
    <option value = "green">Green</option>
    <option value = "red">Red</option>
  </select>
  <input id = "width" type = "number" value = "10"/>
  <button onclick = "pasteHTML()">Get HTMl</button>
  <br/><textarea disabled id = "ta"></textarea>
  
  
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing slow down, because your method of "painting" is extremely inefficient. Everytime a box is added, you do this by adding to `innerHTML`. This means the entire `textarea#ta` is redrawn completely by the browser. So, after minutes (or less) of drawing, the browser is redrawing thousands of `<div>`s many times a second.

Consider looking into 2D graphics with `<canvas>` – [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D).

Or, if you must do this with DOM (it's not what it's meant for!), then at least do it more efficiently with `appendChild` – [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Comment: Thank you. I was aware that it was not meant for that I just wanted a way to draw and convert it to HTML divs.